# Parsing the result of an array formula inline?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I am trying to use `=GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "high", DATE(2022,7,26))`.
According to google's docs, using historical values in this formula will result in an array result...

So, it pumps values all around my table, kinda ruining what I am trying to do:

```
Date        High
44768.67    105.13
```

(all of the above should be just one cell, but the formula results in splatting 4 cells, as array formulas do)

What I need is to get the number `105.13` but I don't have any leads on how to do that. I tried looking into `split()` or `join()` but it seems my use case is not common enough for me to find relevant discussion and/or examples.

Any tips appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Inline, it can look like this: 
`=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "high", DATE(2022,7,26)), 2, 2)`

The "2, 2" part means "2'nd row, 2'nd column" and that's how I point into a cell into this little table the formula creates :)

Comment: Another way to do that is with `=query( googlefinance(B2, "high", "2022-07-26"), "select Col2 label Col2 '' ", 1)`. This pattern may be more tractable when you are calculating averages or otherwise aggregating data.